# Vertical scrollbar appearing in bootstrap navigation, carousel & footer

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a simple 4 page site using Twitter Bootstrap. Although it worked previously, but now scrollbars are appearing in different sections on the home page.

I've got a dropdown on the top menu. Whenever the "Product" menu item is clicked ( https://gyazo.com/8edfee3de1f27861dee5488da2b2a168), rather than showing a dropdown menu, it's producing a menu with a scrollbar.

Similarly, I've also created a carousel below the navigation but scrollbars are appearing on the "previous" and "next" button

The scrollbar is even appearing on the footer

When viewed on a mobile device (an emulator) the icon bars are not being displayed. (https://gyazo.com/7f78dfc4797a135cc3083fa1f6aa8bc2)

Here is the code for the index page:

```
    <?php require_once "inc/functions.php"; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Simex</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php require "inc/navigationTop.php" ?>

        <?php require "inc/slider.php"; ?>

        <?php require "inc/homeTiles.php" ?>

        <?php require "inc/footer.php" ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's the code for the navigation section:

```
<?php require_once "inc/functions.php" ?>
<nav class="navbar navTop">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php" target="_self">Simex</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right navigationList">
        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Products <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="osmosis.php">Reverse Osmosis</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="waterTreat.php">Water Treatment</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="waterBottling.php">Water Bottling Plant</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="vehicles.php">Japanese Reconditional Vehicles</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="seeds.php">Export &amp; Sesame Seeds</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="agri.php">Agri Farming &amp; Equipment</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="aboutUs.php">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="contactUs.php">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
     </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

Comment: Emulator image link: https://gyazo.com/7f78dfc4797a135cc3083fa1f6aa8bc2

Comment: Scrollbar appearing on footer:https://gyazo.com/685b752821c0b4f9627f08a50d095d7a

Comment: This looks like a `CSS` issue, could you include some of that? It seems as though these items you're showing have a fixed height and `overflow: scroll;` which will cause the scroll bar to show.

Comment: Nope doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with the attached stylesheet.

Previous css style:

```
* {
.
.
overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

I erased the overflow-x property and placed it as a property for the body, like:

```
body {
.
.
.
overflow-x:hidden;
}
```